# unordered list items with float:left do not float properly

Tags: css, html-lists

Any help is sincerely appreciated.
For some reason in my unordered list, two last items do not float as expected.
you can see it at `zenmonyDOTcom/immune-support-c30/`
Here is the layout:

```
ul.categories-list {
    width: 620px;
    padding: 30px 0 10px 60px;
    float: left;
    min-height:425px;
    background: url(/images/categories_bkgrnd_main.png) no-repeat;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
}

.categories-list li {
    position:relative;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    }
```

Is it because the items are not cleared properly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from `ul.categories-list` and also modify padding as `30px 0 10px 0`

and add `display: inline-block;` to `.categories-list li` and remove `float: left;` too

```
.categories-list li {
    position:relative;
    margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your heights are not consistent, one of the images is 195px high, while the rest seem to be 194px, if you make them all the same, you should be all set!

Comment: your solution turned out to be better. With solution in the first answer the li elements were located unevenly.